# Property of a morphism inherited by the fibers

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $T$ be a scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$ and let $f:X\to Y$ be a $k$-morphism over $T$.

For which properties **P** is it true that if $f_t:X_t\to Y_t$ has **P** for all geometric points $t\in T(k)$, then $f$ has **P**? Is it true for open immersions, for instance? What about properness, flatness...? (Feel free to add some assumptions, I really have no idea whether I am asking something very strong or not!)

Comment: As it stands, in this generality all of these can be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X,Y$ are flat and of finite presentation over $T$.

Then, let $P$ be a property in $\{$flat, smooth, etale, open immersion, isomorphism, flat and a relative complete intersection morphism$\}$, then $f$ has property $P$ if and only if each $f_t$ has $P$ for all geometric points $t$ in $T$ (Here $T$ doesn't have to be a $k$-scheme).

This is stated in Deligne/Rapoport on page "DeRa-28" (page number 170), section I,(7.4), and he gives references to EGA IV 11.3.10 and 17.9.1. A very special case for $P = $ smooth for curves over Dedekind domains is given in Silverman's Advanced Topics in Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, in the chapter on Neron models, section 2 (or maybe 3, or 4?)

Answer (score 0):

No, open immersion of fibers does not imply actual open immersion.

For example take $T=\mathbb A^1_k, X=\mathbb A^1_k, Y=\mathbb A^2_k$
For the structural morphisms  $X\to T$ take the constant map  $x\mapsto 0$ and for $Y\to T$ take the first projection.
Finally for $X\to Y$ take $x\mapsto (x,0)$, which is not an open embeding but is a fiberwise open embedding.

Comment: Of course you will immediately be tempted to add hypotheses in order to avoid  my counterexample but I'm not sure I'll want or be  able to initiate such an algebraic geometry  ping-pong :-) But go ahead anyway: there are many good souls on this site...

Comment: Thanks Georges! and let me reassure you, I will initiate the ping-pong session with myself - I will not bother innocent people (for the moment) :-)